# If a function is continuously derivable is it also continuously differentiable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I'm doing an computer science online test and my professor is putting loads of trick questions in in. I'm wondering whether this is also one.

I have a question for which we stated at the lectures that (some specific function we're talking about) f(x) is **continuously derivable**

However, now at the online test there is a (true/false) statement that says that this very function  is **continuously differentiable**

Now I do understand this basic math terms but I'm a bit unsure whether this is the same and he's using only different terms for it. Or is this really as trick question and the answer is false...

I have to mark the statement as true or false. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: It depends on how you define derivability, I dont't think it's a standard mathematical concept. By the way, are you allowed to ask for external help during that test?

Comment: yes. Thank you for your concern. It's awfully helpful

Comment: "Derivable" is a French alternative to "differentiable" (which also exists) hence there is zero difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realise that this answer has come much much too late, but maybe some others will have similar questions to yours in the future.

To begin with, the term "derivable" isn't used in English when doing mathematics. It does, however, exist in various romance languages as well as, weirdly enough, Chinese (possibly influenced by the Soviet school). My impressions are that even in those languages, the definition of derivable might not be completely uniform. However, it does at the very least assert that your function has partial derivatives (I've seen also some sources use derivable to mean that directional derivatives exist). To be clear, derivable functions are NOT always differentiable. Consider

$f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$, when $(x,y)$ isn't the origin, and $f(0,0)=0$.

This isn't even a continuous function (and hence isn't differentiable)!

(The stronger version of derivable where all directional derivatives exist isn't necessarily differentiable either, maybe someone reading this can work out an example)

And now, we come to "continuously derivable". This actually means that the function has partial derivatives, and the derivatives are continuous. To be clear, the standard mathematical nomenclature for this is that the function is of (differentiability) class C^1. Then, one can show that this is enough to actually ensure that the function is differentiable, and not only differentiable, but continuously differentiable (meaning that the function is differentiable, and that its total derivative (not partial derivative) is continuous. To be clear, a priori, continuously differentiable functions are definitely continuously derivable, but it's not obvious that these two concepts are equivalent. One needs to do some hard work to show that they are indeed equal!

This...is needlessly complicated. In reality, no-one except maybe mathematicians and math majors ever really deal with functions which are (only) derivable, and probably the only reason that this is covered in a course is to train your ability to distinguish between subtly different abstract concepts. Which, I guess, could be a useful skill?